# How to fill a Word 2016 form with data stored in an Access 2016 database.?

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-word, vba

I am working on a small project and I need to be able to fill a Word 2016 form with data stored in an Access 2016 database. To do so, I have created a form (Customers) with a button (Save). When clicking the button, the data from the form whould be saved to the table (Customers) and also sent to the Word form. This is the code I have following the instructions from [Techrepublic.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-do-i-fill-word-form-fields-with-access-data/)

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()

'Print customer slip for current customer.

Dim appWord As Word.Application

Dim doc As Word.Document

'Avoid error 429, when Word isn't open.

On Error Resume Next

Err.Clear

'Set appWord object variable to running instance of Word.

Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If Err.Number <> 0 Then

'If Word isn't open, create a new instance of Word.

Set appWord = New Word.Application

End If

Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open("E:\Usuarios\Acrocephalus\Daniel\Projectes\AnemaDB\ProgramaControlDDD2015.docx", , True)

With doc

.FormFields("fldIDClient").Result = Me!IDClient

.FormFields("fldNomLocal").Result = Me!NomLocal

.FormFields("fldNomFiscal").Result = Me!NomFiscal

.FormFields("fldNIF_CIF").Result = Me!NIF_CIF

.FormFields("fldTipusVia").Result = Me!TipusVia

.FormFields("fldAdreca").Result = Me!Adreca

.FormFields("fldCP").Result = Me!CP

.FormFields("fldMunicipi").Result = Me!Municipi

.FormFields("fldProvincia").Result = Me!Provincia

.FormFields("fldFix").Result = Me!Fix

.FormFields("fldMobile").Result = Me!Mobile

.FormFields("fldemail").Result = Me!email
.Visible = True

.Activate

End With

Set doc = Nothing

Set appWord = Nothing

Exit Sub

errHandler:

MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

However, when I fill in the data and click on the button I have 3 problems:

1. It doesn't save any data into the table
2. It doesn't fill the Word
3. I have to press the button twice to open the form.

Can anyone help?
Thanks!!

Dani

Comment: You need to add a reference to the Word application library in your Access VB project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the correct References in VBA?

On the VBA Editor press Tools > References, and put a check before Microsoft Work xx.0 Object Library

Comment: Thanks,I am starting with access, so sorry about such a stupid question. Can you please have a look at my new edited question? I have some new problems. Thanks again!

Comment: 1.Nowhere in the code you are saving the data to the table. Now, Access usually does this on it's own when closing the form, but only if the form has a table already in it's properties. The vba command to close a form, and save it's data into the table is 'DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form Name", acSaveYes'. If you want to be prompted to save instead, use acSavePrompt. For the other 2 problems, it's harder. Does it give you any error when you remove 'On Error Resume Next'?

Comment: Try debugging and going through the code step by step. Click on the line of your code you want the code to stop, on the left grey bar, you'll see the editor put a circle there. Run the program, and it'll stop when it reaches that line. Then just debug > Step into (or F8) will run the code one line at a time, allowing you to see if it's skipping some IFs or ignoring any line of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for not giving any feedback before. I'll try your suggestions.